How can I Retrieve Notion Note URLs in an Apple Shortcut?
I'm struggling to get the Url into my database notion. Here is one of the 400 i get :
{"status":400,"object":"error","code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation: body.parent should be defined, instead was `undefined`.","request_id":"2e0260e1-985f-4b04-99e7-50cbc5607d6f"}

I think that i'm not using correctly the keys flow...
I'm in the process of creating an Apple Shortcut to automate note-taking into Notion. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to fetch the URL for each note within the shortcut. Can someone provide guidance on the best approach to accomplish this task efficiently? Any assistance or example code snippets would be immensely helpful. Thank you!



I've done it. It was more simple to do this way :
